# Separating div object(fc-event) for the event with multiple days

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Working external event dragging with jquery fullcalendar.

I would like to know, when an user extends a event to some more dates by using handle bar drag, if there are any possibilities to create multiple event `div` `object(fc-event)`?

Now its showing only one div (`fc-event`) for all selected days, this need to be separate `div`s(`fc-event`) for each day.

Comment: So on drag expand you want to create separate events instead extending the dragged one?

Comment: @Irvin Yes, you are right.

Comment: you can e.g use [eventResize](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) to split event after resizing stops. But please try to write something yourself first and then post here code you have troubles with

Comment: I'll try using eventResize, really appreciate if you can give any hint for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eventResize`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) event:

> Triggered when resizing stops and the event has changed in duration.

in the event clone the element and set new start/end date on it then render it on the calendar using `renderEvent` method; at the end remember to revert the standard resize effect using `revertFunc`

Code:

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [{
        title: 'event1',
        start: '2014-05-02'
    }, {
        title: 'event2',
        start: '2014-05-10'
    }],
    eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
        var originalEventObject = event;

        for (var i = 0; i < dayDelta; i++) {
            var selectedIndex = parseInt(originalEventObject._id.replace(/_fc/, '') - 1);
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, $("#mycalendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents")[selectedIndex]);
            copiedEventObject.source = null;
            var newDay = new Date(copiedEventObject.start);
            newDay.setDate(newDay.getDate() + i + 1);
            copiedEventObject._id = "_fc" + parseInt($("#mycalendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents").length + 1);
            copiedEventObject.start = newDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = newDay;
            $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
        }

        revertFunc();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/p9JFq/

Comment: @Jaison you are welcome; if solved consider to accept the answer using the tick (check your older questions too :-)